# Basic Authentication creating a Welcome site

Tags: security, tomcat, basic-authentication

I have a TomcatServer with a RDF4J Triplestore. Basic Authentication is active on the whole server and the Triplestore. As soon i go to one of the site´s i get ask for a username and password in a popup - as intended.

Now i was wondering if it would be possible to create a "Welcome" Page on that same Tomcat. What would be "public" for everyone. With some Information and a login for users. I found lots of tutorials and how to on sending the login over the url and Httpreqest and so on.

What would be a good way to do that ? 
Creating a page somewhere else ? With a login Feld and than going on the actual site ?

Or "deaktivate" BA for the Welcome Site only ? Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks for your input and time.

Comment: As mentioned in the below answer, form based authentication is the answer and another point o fnote is that BASIC and form authentication cannot be used simultaneously on a single web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The soulution for this problem is: Form based Authentication. 
There your free to create a Login page and a error page. And it completly removes the Popup window also.